# DSC Azure Install exe as an administrator

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

I'm using a Resource Manager template in azure to create a VM and using a DSC extension to install a executable once the VM has been created. I have the fundamentals working ie it downloads my file to a directory and installs a test executable. This particular executable is installed at a machine level.

The executable I need to to install must be installed at a user level, not machine level.

I've tried a couple of approaches.

```
            $username = 'username'
            $password = 'password'
            $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
            $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
            Start-Process "C:\Deployment\installer.exe" -Credential $credential -ArgumentList ' /S -noprofile -command &{Start-Process -verb runas}'
```

I've also tried starting another process

```
            $password = convertto-securestring "password" -asplaintext -force
            $psi = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
            $psi.UseShellExecute = $false
            $psi.UserName = "username"
            $psi.Password = $password
            $psi.FileName = $dest 
            $psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
            $psi.Arguments = " /S"
            $proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
            $result = $proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
            $proc.WaitForExit()
```

I've also tried a CustomExtension in the Azure Resource Template and still the same.

Comment: Can you post your DSC configuration?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The user requires elevated permissions. The user that this is running under is an admin. From what I can see this all runs under the system account. I've spoken to a colleague and said to try impersonation.